# How to search from sql server

Tags: javascript, c#

I have DB in SQL server management studio.
The Employee has first_name, last_name, and department.
The code in c#:

```
        private FactoryDBEntities db = new FactoryDBEntities();

    public List<Employee> GetEmployees(string fname,string lname, int department)
    {
        if (fname == "" && lname == "" && department == 0)
        {
            return db.Employee.ToList();
        }
        else if(fname!=""&& lname == "" && department == 0)
        {
          
            return db.Employee.Where(x => x.First_Name == fname).ToList();
        }
        else if(fname == "" && lname != "" && department == 0)
        {
            return db.Employee.Where(x => x.Last_Name == lname).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return db.Employee.Where(x => x.DepartmentID == department).ToList();
        }
        
    }
```

now I want to send from javascript to search but I don't know how I can send this.

for example from postman I send: `https://localhost:44341/api/Employee?fname=John`
and I received the data that I want.
Thanks.

Comment: Why the sql-server tag ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

```
fetch('https://localhost:44341/api/Employee?fname=John')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```